# How to Embed .FLV in Adobe Air Application. Flash CS6

Tags: flash, air, flv, flash-cs6

I've got a project that needs to be packed up as an Adobe AIR application, and needs to be able to play video. The video in question is too large to be included in the timeline, so the file in question needs to be packed up as a part of the AIR application.

No matter what settings I use, I cannot seem to make the .FLV show up in the published product.

What am I doing wrong, or what do I need to do to package a .FLV video into an AIR application in such a way that it is viewable within the application?

Editing to add that I've already added the .FLV to included files under publish settings, and added the following actionscript.

```
import fl.video.FLVPlayback;
import fl.video.VideoPlayer;
import fl.video.flvplayback_internal;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.media.StageVideo;
```

Comment: adding the .flv to the included files list under publish settings, and`import fl.video.FLVPlayback;
import fl.video.VideoPlayer;
import fl.video.flvplayback_internal;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.media.StageVideo;`

Comment: what settings are you giving the FLVplayback component?

Comment: try opening your final AIR app in WinZip (or similar) - is the flv file listed as part of the contents?

Comment: I have the "autoplay" setting checked in the FLVPlayback component options. The .FLV file is showing up inside the package. It simply won't show up and play in the final package.

Comment: i assume theres a problem with the filepath you set - not matching where the flv is stored

Comment: And yet the .FLV is being properly packed into the AIR application.

Answer (score 1):

I have that same problem with my project. I had 80 videos packaged inside my apk file = 1.023Gb. Testing the app on my desktop reveals no problem at all but when installed on my device some videos are not playing. All my videos are of the same FLV 320x240 format but with different duration. I'm guessing maybe its the device's limited hardware specs causing the videos not to play. When you install your apk file on the device, it remains as an apk file. The file will be mounted (like a ROM) on the device when you run the application therefore if the device does not have enough ROM to mount your app some of the files will not be mounted.

What I did is I installed a third party app SWF player from BIT LABS. Instead of publishing out as an apk file, i just copied my proj swf file, component swf and video files to my device and run the project using the SWF player app.